# matching of dates using regex pattern

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I was trying to match a date pattern 25.8.2020 using regex pattern. I used [\d]{1,2}.[\d]{1,2}.[\d]{4} for matching this. But the problem is that if there are some sequence like 454.9451, 2021-2022 etc they are also getting matched. How can i write a regex pattern for matching exactly only dd.mm.yyyy format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `[0-3]*\d\.[01]*\d\.\d{4}`
Using `\.` instead `.`

Example: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DMsVAB/1)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `strptime` to validate the date string in your expected format:

```py
def validate(date_text):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%d.%m.%Y')
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("invalid date string " + date_text)

inp = ['25.8.2020', '2020-12-31']
for i in inp:
    validate(i)
```

This prints:

> ValueError: invalid date string 2020-12-31

The potential advantage of using `strptime` over a pure regex is that the latter might also admit strings which match the pattern but are invalid dates.  For example, the pattern `\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}` by itself would allow for dates such as `30.02.2021`, which don't really exist.